# Why does this solution works in JavaScript but takes too long in C++? (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: javascript, c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

This is what my `canSum` function needs to do:

#### **Given a target sum `x`, return `true` iff it is possible to get that sum by adding elements from a given array, assuming array elements can be used any number of times.**

Examples:

```
canSum(7, {2,3}) -> true
canSum(7, {2,4}) -> false
```

Below is the JavaScript code which I rewrote in C++. For some reason, even though I used memoization, the C++ version takes too long for big inputs.

The JavaScript code, which works fine:

```
const canSum = (targetSum, numbers, memo={}) => {
    if (targetSum === 0) return true;
    if (targetSum < 0) return false;
    for ( let num of numbers) {
        const remainder = targetSum - num;
        if (canSum( remainder, numbers, memo) === true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};


console.log(canSum(7, [2, 3])); // true
console.log(canSum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7])); // true
console.log(canSum(7, [2, 41])); // false
console.log(canSum(8, [2, 3, 5])); // true
console.log(canSum(300, [7, 14])); // false
```

My C++ code, which never gave any output for the last input item `canSum(300, {7,14})`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

unordered_map<int,bool> mymap;

bool canSum(int goal, vector<int> vec)
{
    if (goal<0)       return false;
    if (goal==0)      return true;
    if (mymap[goal])  return mymap[goal];

    for(auto&ell:vec)
    {
        if(canSum(goal-ell,vec)==true) 
        {
            mymap.insert({goal,true});
            return true;
        }
    }
    mymap.insert({goal,false});
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<canSum(7, {2,3})<<endl;
    cout<<canSum(7, {5,3,4,7})<<endl;
    cout<<canSum(7, {2,4})<<endl;
    cout<<canSum(8, {2,3,5})<<endl;
    cout<<canSum(300, {7,14})<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I optimize the C++ code, and why is the JavaScript code faster ?

Comment: *why is the js code faster?* -- Where is the proof that the C++ code is slow?  Questions asking "why is this slow?" are to be accompanied by the compiler used, compiler options used to build the application, whether you are building with optimizations turned on, and an actual C++ code that has timing functions that tests and outputs this information (or the code is run on an online performance tester).

Comment: javascript probably passes objects by references whereas `C++` passes a copy unless you tell it different. Maybe try `bool canSum(int goal, vector<int> const& vec)` ? Also compile using optimizations.

Comment: `if (mymap[goal]) return mymap[goal];` -- What is your intention here?  If it is to search the map to see if `goal` is already in the map, that line of code does not do that.  A classic case of doing line-by-line translations from another language to C++, and tripping up and failing.

Comment: And note, using `[ ]` to access the map in C++ will automatically insert an entry if the entry isn't in the map.  Another issue -- you are doing potentially two lookups by using `[ ]` twice on that line.  Basically, that line of code needs to be rewritten to do an actual search *once*, and given whether the value is there, do something with that value.  The unordered_map has a `find()` method you should be using, instead of blindly using `[ ]`.  The `find()` will return an iterator to the existing item, or `end()` if the item isn't there.

Comment: You do not seem to reset your *global* map object between 2 calls to canSum().

Comment: @jpmarinier Thanks it works after clear the map (map::clear()) after each call to canSum(). Thanks a lot

Comment: Very similar question here: [SO-q66721219](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721219/dynamic-programming-cansum-memoization-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A difference between your JavaScript and C++ code samples is: the C++ function has just two parameters instead of 3, the map object being managed as a global entity.

In some sense, having just 2 parameters is “*The Right Thing*”. The unordered map is about some internal necessity of the algorithm. Why should user code have to know about that ?

And should you some day decide to use instead an *ordered* map or a set or a bit vector, why should that force user code to change the list of header files it has to #include ?

So having just 2 parameters is fine, however managing the map as an external **global object** is not that good. In C++ programming, global objects are generally frowned upon. In your case, it puts an undue burden on user code, such as having to reset the map object between two calls to `canSum()` ? Such a precaution is all too easily forgotten.

To solve the problem, you could use two C++ functions: an external one, and the internal one.

The external one takes care (internally) of the life cycle of the map object. The internal one just passes a pointer to the map object around.

**C++ code for the *internal* function:**

```
#include  <vector>
#include  <unordered_map>
#include  <iostream>

using  MyMapType = std::unordered_map<int, bool>;  // ad hoc map type
using  std::vector;

bool canSumWithMap(int goal, const vector<int>& vec, MyMapType& myMap)
{
    if (goal < 0)   return false;
    if (goal == 0)  return true;

    if (myMap[goal])
        return myMap[goal];

    for (auto& ell : vec)
    {
        if (canSumWithMap(goal-ell, vec, myMap)) 
        {
            myMap.insert({goal, true});
            return true;
        }
    }
    myMap.insert({goal, false});
    return false;
}
```

Please note that both the map and the vector are passed by *reference*, with a '&' character, in order to avoid unnecessary copying during function calls.

**C++ code for the *external* function, plus main program:**

```
bool canSum(int goal, const vector<int>& vec)
{
    MyMapType  myMap;  // new map object initialized as empty

    bool rc = canSumWithMap(goal, vec, myMap);

    return rc;
    // myMap automagically deallocated here
}


using  std::cout;
using  std::endl;


int main()
{
    cout << std::boolalpha;  // want to print true or false rather than 0 or 1
    cout << canSum(7, {2,3})      << endl;
    cout << canSum(7, {5,3,4,7})  << endl;
    cout << canSum(7, {2,4})      << endl;  // no, can only do multiples of 2
    cout << canSum(8, {2,3,5})    << endl;
    cout << canSum(300, {7,14})   << endl;  // no, can only do multiples of 7

    return 0;
}
```

The above code runs successfully on my semi-vintage Intel x86-64 machine in 50 seconds, GNU C++ v10.2, with -O2 option.

**Program output:**

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)
Copyright © 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  ...  
$ 
$ g++ -O2 q66720598.cpp  -o q66720598.x
$ time q66720598.x
true
true
false
true
false

real   0m49,986s
user   0m49,841s
sys    0m0,003s
$
```

### Performance measurements:

On my machine, your JavaScript codes runs in 19 seconds. And C++ with unordered maps takes 50 seconds, which is a bit disappointing.

Switching from unordered maps to plain (ordered) maps decreases the C++ time to 36 seconds, that's still slower than JavaScript.

It takes a *bit vector*, defined like this:

```
    std::vector<bool>  myMap(goal+1, false);
```

to restore proper hierarchy :-) and make C++  3 times *faster* than JavaScript, with a wall time of only 6 seconds.

So this is one of those situations where map objects, though functionally quite powerful and versatile, can be way slower than some *ad hoc* data structure.

Comment: Thannk you so so much for taking the time to explain this so in depth! Really appreciate it!!